# Subscriptions to model lifecycle events accumulate

Tags: ember.js

When updating a record, I do the following:

```
...
this.transaction.commit();
entry.on("didUpdate", this.afterSave.bind(this, success_msg));
```

But my function `afterSave` "accumulates" on the run loop (no better way to describe it). That is, the first time that I edit a record, `afterSave` is called once. The second time, it is called twice, and so on.

What am I doing wrong here?

### EDIT

According to the [model lifecycle](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/#toc_model-lifecycle), `record.on` subscribes to events. When I want to save en edited record, I basically do the following:

- update the model data, updating some derived properties from the view
- commit the transaction
- suscribe to the `didUpdate` event, to notify the user and perform some final cleanup

So, every time that I edit the record, I suscribe to the `didUpdate` event. I expected that this was a one-time suscription. That is: I suscribe, the event is fired, I handle it, done and forgotten.

But maybe Ember practices are not supposed to work like this. It seems that I each time I call `.on('didUpdate'` the old suscription is still remembered. Is this so? I do not want to do this. How can I do one of these:

- remove any existing suscriptions from the current record
- or get a fresh record, so that I can suscribe to events from scratch. Currently I get the record with `this.get('content')`

Comment: does it also happen when you use a simple callback without the `bind` like `entry.on("didUpdate", function() {console.log('didUpdate')});`?

Comment: @intuitivepixel: yes, it also happens with the simple function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess to avoid accumulation of subscriptions you should use `one`: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html#method_one as a one time subscription. `one` subscribes a function to a named `event` and then cancels the subscription after the first time the event is triggered.

> remove any existing subscription

As for the unsubscription, you could do it with `on`'s counterpart `off`: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html#method_off

Hope this helps.